# Can I generate a quarterly report of Donors without the dollar amounts?

Tags: civicontribute, contacts

We have a group called "Donors". I want to obtain the number of new Donors each quarter, but do not wants the amount they are contributing as I can gain that from other reports.
If possible I would like the result to be in graph format on the home page.

Answer (score 1):

how about using the extension -> https://civicrm.org/extensions/donor-trends-extension

Comment: That extension does not work with the latest Civi. Using 5.38.1. It does not install. I'd think you could make Search Kit do those donor groups.